# Deleting elements in html

Tags: javascript, html

When i click delete button and remove items too fast... all items gets deleted instantly. not one by one... (dont get hard on me... i only have 4 hours of javascript)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjMQt.jpg

[image]

```
count = 0;
cnt = 0;
array = [];

function add() {
var x = document.getElementById("add").value;

    if(x != ""){
        var uppercaseFirstLetter = x.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
        var stringWithoutFirstLetter = x.slice(1)
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.setAttribute("id", x);
        array[count] = x;
        div.className = 'a';

        div.innerHTML =
        '<label id="asd">' + uppercaseFirstLetter + stringWithoutFirstLetter + '</label>\
        <img id="delete" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/148/148973.svg" onClick="reply_click(parentNode.id)">\
        <img id="tick" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/149/149148.svg" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">';

    document.getElementById('w').appendChild(div);
    document.getElementById('add').value = '';
    document.getElementById("add").focus();
    count++;

    }
}

function reply_click(clicked_id)
{   

    if(clicked_id != "tick"){


var elem = document.getElementById(clicked_id);
elem.remove();

        document.getElementById("add").focus();
    }
    else{
        alert("tick");

    }
}
```

Comment: you should post all html and script to question to reproduce

Comment: your naming isn't that explicit, some context (i.e the html) would be useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   function reply_click(){
        var item = this.parentNode.parentNode;
        var parent = item.parentNode;
        var id = parent.id;
        var value = item.innerText;
        parent.removeChild(item);
    }
```

May be this code work for you.
You can see a live demo. http://codeleson.com/todolist/